# Get overridden config with Middleware from Service Provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, service-provider, laravel-middleware

I have a problem when binding Class in service container. this is my route.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'partner', 'domain' => '{partner}.example.com'], function() {
    $firebaseClient = app('App\Services\FirebaseClient');
    $firebaseClient->pushData('users.json', ['name' => 'Risal Ganteng']);
});
```

this is my custom service provider for binding FirebaseClient.

```
class FirebaseClientServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{

    /**
    * Register FirebaseClient class with the Laravel IoC container.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(\App\Services\FirebaseClient::class, function($app)
        {
            $config = $app['config'];

            $options = [
                'api_version' => $config['services.firebase.api_version']
            ];

            return new \App\Services\FirebaseClient($config['services.firebase.database_url'], $options);
        });
    }
}
```

and this is my custom route middleware to overide config services.firebase based on subdomain.

```
class PartnerMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $partner_id = $request->route('partner');

        $partner = Partner::findOrFail($partner_id);

        // set config
        config([
            'services.firebase.api_key' => $partner->firebase_api_key,
            'services.firebase.auth_domain' => $partner->firebase_auth_domain,
            'services.firebase.database_url' => $partner->firebase_database_url,
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I try to get config in FirebaseServiceProvider the config services.firebase.* value is null because ServiceProvider registered before Route Middleware.

and how to resolve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not register your service provider in `config/app.php` file. Register `FirebaseClientServiceProvider` provider in `PartnerMiddleware` middleware dynamically.

```
class PartnerMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $partner_id = $request->route('partner');

        $partner = Partner::findOrFail($partner_id);

        // set config
        config([
            'services.firebase.api_key' => $partner->firebase_api_key,
            'services.firebase.auth_domain' => $partner->firebase_auth_domain,
            'services.firebase.database_url' => $partner->firebase_database_url,
        ]);


        app()->register(FirebaseClientServiceProvider::class);


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, middleware executes much, much later than your service provider so overriding config has no effect. You have to bind your service *after* you change the config.

Why don't you move the binding to middleware? Just copy paste the whole block from register() and put it after config() in your middleware.

Alternatively, instead of resolving through service container, you could attach Firebase client to Request object in the middleware, after config().